# Using Javascript 2D array duplicate record in one row by adding one property value with final array only unique record with modified properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Question Array:

```
    let array=[
    
        ["a23","3000","0","ES08"],
        ["a23","3000","0","ES93"],
        ["a23","3000","0","ES71"],
        ["12w","3007","0","ES34"],
        ["12w","3007","0","ES56"],
        ["1v8","3008","0","ES08"]
    
    ]
```

Condition:
Duplicate record constraints array[0][0]+array[0][1] equal to array[1][0]+array[1][1].....etc

Expected Result:

```
  array= [
    
        ["a23","3000","0","ES08ES93ES71"],
        ["12w","3007","0","ES34ES56"],
        ["1v8","3008","0","ES08"]
    
    ]
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far it seems like you are taking an exam with question and expected output

Answer (score -1):

Simple approach would be :

- Group elements and accumulate last element (which contains different `ES*`) in an array:
  `{ "a2330000": [["ES08"], ["ES93"], ["ES71"]], "12w30070": [["ES34"], ["ES56"]], "1v830080": [["ES08"]], }`
- Loop again to get those accumulated `ES*` and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/join) them back.

```js
let array=[ ["a23","3000","0","ES08"], ["a23","3000","0","ES93"], ["a23","3000","0","ES71"], ["12w","3007","0","ES34"], ["12w","3007","0","ES56"], ["1v8","3008","0","ES08"] ];
let obj = {}
for (let arr of array) {
    let key = arr.slice(0,-1).join('');
    obj[key]??= [];
    obj[key].push(arr.slice(-1));
}
let output = []
for (let arr of array) {
    let key = arr.slice(0,-1).join('');
    if(obj[key] && !obj[key].visited){
        output.push([...arr.slice(0,-1),obj[key].join('')])
        obj[key].visited = true;
    }
}
console.log(output)
```

**Note:** I added `visited` property just to not create duplicate inner `arrays` of the same *id key* (*combination of three first element of inner array*)